# Measuring seasonality effect

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, trend

I am working on a research problem related to time series analysis. Now, I have STL decomposition and FB Prophet to decompose my data into trend, seasonality and residual. I struggle with measuring the strength of my seasonality component. In the book [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/complexseasonality.html), there is a formula which is the ratio of var(residual) to var(residual + seasonality) (takes 0 if negative).
Yet, it's very difficult to build an intuition behind it, on repeated trials it shows that daily seasonality is pretty much zero (though my algorithms suggest that there is one.)
I would appreciate any hints and suggestions as to measuring the strength of seasonality. Thank you!